# Swift - Detect Tap on child SCNNode not Parent

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scnnode

I have a simple interactive globe represented by dots. Every dot is a `SCNNode` and the globe is also a `SCNNode`. The Entire globe node is the parent, and the smaller dots within the globe are children. I want to detect taps on the child nodes.

When I try doing, so the tap gestures are detected only for the parent node and because of this I cannot determine which child node is clicked. Ultimately, I want to click on a child node (dot) and determine the SCNVector3 of the position clicked, so I can convert to coordinates.

I've been working on the function **touchesBegan**, but this picks up clicks on the parent earth node.

When I print the tappedNode I get **`<SCNNode: 0x134c46790 | geometry=<SCNGeometry: 0x6000035277b0> | 14427 children>`** this indicates the earth node with 14427 children (dots).

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit
import CoreImage
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

public typealias GenericController = UIViewController

public class GlobeViewController: GenericController {
    var nodePos: CGPoint? = nil
    public var earthNode: SCNNode!
    private var sceneView : SCNView!
    private var cameraNode: SCNNode!
    private var dotCount = 50000
    
    public init(earthRadius: Double) {
        self.earthRadius = earthRadius
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    public init(earthRadius: Double, dotCount: Int) {
        self.earthRadius = earthRadius
        self.dotCount = dotCount
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first, touch.view == self.sceneView else {
            return
        }

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: sceneView)
        let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, options: nil)
        
        let touchLocation3D = sceneView.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(Float(touchLocation.x), Float(touchLocation.y), 0.0))
        
        print(touchLocation3D)
        
        if let tappedNode = hitTestResults.first?.node {
            print(tappedNode)
            // Handle the tapped node
            if tappedNode.name == "NewYorkDot" {
                // This is the New York dot, perform your action here
                print("Tapped on New York! Position: \(tappedNode.position)")
            } else if tappedNode.name == "RegularDot" {
                // Handle other nodes if needed
                print("Tapped on a regular dot. Position: \(tappedNode.position)")
            }
        }
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupScene()
        
        setupParticles()
        
        setupCamera()
        setupGlobe()
        
        setupDotGeometry()
    }
    
    private func setupScene() {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView = SCNView(frame: view.frame)
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
    }
        
    private func setupParticles() {
        guard let stars = SCNParticleSystem(named: "StarsParticles.scnp", inDirectory: nil) else { return }
        stars.isLightingEnabled = false
                
        if sceneView != nil {
            sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addParticleSystem(stars)
        }
    }
    
    private func setupCamera() {
        self.cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    }

    private func setupGlobe() {
        self.earthNode = EarthNode(radius: earthRadius, earthColor: earthColor, earthGlow: glowColor, earthReflection: reflectionColor)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)
    }

    private func setupDotGeometry() {
        let textureMap = generateTextureMap(dots: dotCount, sphereRadius: CGFloat(earthRadius))

        let newYork = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.0682, longitude: -121.3153)
        let newYorkDot = closestDotPosition(to: newYork, in: textureMap)

        let dotColor = GenericColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
        let oceanColor = GenericColor(cgColor: UIColor.systemRed.cgColor)
        let highlightColor = GenericColor(cgColor: UIColor.systemRed.cgColor)
        
        // threshold to determine if the pixel in the earth-dark.jpg represents terrain (0.03 represents rgb(7.65,7.65,7.65), which is almost black)
        let threshold: CGFloat = 0.03
        
        let dotGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
        dotGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = dotColor
        dotGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        
        let highlightGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
        highlightGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = highlightColor
        highlightGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        
        let oceanGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
        oceanGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = oceanColor
        oceanGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        
        var positions = [SCNVector3]()
        var dotNodes = [SCNNode]()
        
        var highlightedNode: SCNNode? = nil
        
        for i in 0...textureMap.count - 1 {
            let u = textureMap[i].x
            let v = textureMap[i].y
            
            let pixelColor = self.getPixelColor(x: Int(u), y: Int(v))
            let isHighlight = u == newYorkDot.x && v == newYorkDot.y
            
            if (isHighlight) {
                let dotNode = SCNNode(geometry: highlightGeometry)
                dotNode.name = "NewYorkDot"
                dotNode.position = textureMap[i].position
                positions.append(dotNode.position)
                dotNodes.append(dotNode)
                
                print("myloc \(textureMap[i].position)")
                
                highlightedNode = dotNode
            } else if (pixelColor.red < threshold && pixelColor.green < threshold && pixelColor.blue < threshold) {
                let dotNode = SCNNode(geometry: dotGeometry)
                dotNode.name = "Other"
                dotNode.position = textureMap[i].position
                positions.append(dotNode.position)
                dotNodes.append(dotNode)
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let dotPositions = positions as NSArray
            let dotIndices = NSArray()
            let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: dotPositions as! [SCNVector3])
            let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: dotIndices as! [Int32], primitiveType: .point)
            
            let pointCloud = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
            
            let pointCloudNode = SCNNode(geometry: pointCloud)
            for dotNode in dotNodes {
                pointCloudNode.addChildNode(dotNode)
            }
     
            self.sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(pointCloudNode)
            
        }
   }
}


typealias GenericControllerRepresentable = UIViewControllerRepresentable

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private struct GlobeViewControllerRepresentable: GenericControllerRepresentable {
    var particles: SCNParticleSystem? = nil

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> GlobeViewController {
        let globeController = GlobeViewController(earthRadius: 1.0)
        updateGlobeController(globeController)
        return globeController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GlobeViewController, context: Context) { }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
public struct GlobeView: View {
    public var body: some View {
        GlobeViewControllerRepresentable()
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an incredible amount of code and still not reproducible, you should minimize your code to a reproducible example. We dont need everything just the bare minimum needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @loremipsum fixed

Comment: @ahmed `if let tappedNode = hitTestResults.first?.node {` your problem is in this line. You are only checking the first hit node...  of course it is going to be the parent. Several ways to fix, such as removing the collision from the parent. This would mean the hit test only triggers on the objects with collision. You could also just going through the hit test results (with a for loop) until you find a "non-earth" object.

Comment: @ColdLogic thanks a lot!! That was the problem. Also touchesBegan and touchesEnded pick up all other gestures (drag, magnification, etc) is there a different function I can override that only detects taps?

Comment: @ColdLogic I added a new question for my comment above if you can look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77533732/detect-touches-and-ignore-other-gestures-swift-scenekit

Comment: @ahmed You have to use gesture recognizers if you want only specific things to happen during specific gestures. You can sort of accomplish the same thing with touchesBegan by checking the number of taps, state of the touch, and other factors. But its easier to just use a UIPanGestureRecognizer or a UITapGestureRecognizer. Search SceneKit gesture recognizer and you should find example code